# Cannot find error while destructuring arguments in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm porting some code to TypeScript, and a bit stumped by this error. The `SomeObject` type is supposed to allow an object with any named keys which equate to string values. When using in unpacked argument fields, I get two errors:

> 'SomeObject' is declared but its value is never read.

and

> Cannot find name 'someArg'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.someArg'?

Here's the code:

```js
type SomeObject = { [key: string]: string; }

class SomeClass {

  someArg: SomeObject

  constructor ({someArg: SomeObject} = {}) {
    this.someArg = someArg
  }
}

module.exports = SomeClass;
```

Here you can see where TypeScript has a problem in VS Code:

[image]

Am I missing something? I would expect to be able to create an instance of this class like so:

```js
new SomeClass({someArg: {hello: 'world'}}) // Passes TypeScript

new SomeClass({someArg: {hello: 1}}) // Fails TypeScript as value is not a string
```

Comment: `{someArg: SomeObject} = {}` - this doesn't looks right to me. Is this destructuring or are you specifying type for `someArg`? My guess is that this ambiguity is causing the issue.

Comment: This is destructuring or "argument unpacking" in JS. Perhaps this is confusing TypeScript but there is a lot of this in the codebase that I'm porting so I need a way of converting appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your type in this way:

```js
type SomeObject = { [key: string]: string; }

class SomeClass {

  someArg: SomeObject

  constructor({ someArg }: { [key: string]: SomeObject } = {}) {
    this.someArg = someArg
  }
}
```

Since `someArg` is optional, you should use indexed type, or you can use `Record<string, SomeObject>` instead of `{ [key: string]: SomeObject }`

**UPDATE**

```js
type SomeObject = { [key: string]: string; }

class SomeClass {

    someArg: SomeObject | undefined

    constructor({ someArg }: { someArg?: SomeObject } & Record<PropertyKey, any> = {}) {
        this.someArg = someArg
    }
}

const x = new SomeClass({}) // ok
const y = new SomeClass({ age: 42 }).someArg // ok
const z = new SomeClass({ someArg: { age: '42' } }).someArg // ok
```

More about destructuring in Typescript you can find in [this article](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript)

Comment: Surely the above would mean that any property I added to the incoming argument must also be of type `SomeObject`. This is no good if I need different types from differing destructured properties.

Comment: Ok, so I think reading about it [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript) it seems that, because `{foo: bar}` is actually a valid syntax in JavaScript, TypeScript must be much more verbose when dealing with [destrucutring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Your answer is good but it might be worth linking the article. Will mark as correct.

Comment: @shennan added link to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove you {} and use...

```
type SomeObject = { [key: string]: string; }

class SomeClass {

  someArg: SomeObject

  constructor (someArg: SomeObject = {}) {
    this.someArg = someArg
  }
}

class fred {

    fredJnr:SomeClass = new SomeClass( { Hello: "fred"})
}
module.exports = SomeClass;
```

Does that work for your use case?

Comment: No, `someArg` is a property of an object passed to `SomeClass`. Initialising signature should be `new SomeClass({someArg: { Hello: "fred"}})`